# UI jQuery Tabs - Create More than One Link to Tabs within Tabs on Same Page

Tags: hyperlink, jquery-ui-tabs

My code so far:

```
$(function(){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({ axis: "x" });                         
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $tabs = $("#tabs").tabs();
            $('#tabs-1 a').click( function(){
                $tabs.tabs('select', 4); });

});
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tabs-2">Alarms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Access Control</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
          <p><span class="bodytext">Check our services</span></p> //want to link to tab 4(services)
          <p><span class="bodytext">
          <a href="#tabs-5">Contact us</a>for free 24hours a day...</span></p>
```

As you can see from the code when you click on "Contact us" text in tab 1 there is a link to tab 5.
What i want to do is to create a link from "Check our services" to tab 4. 
In general to create over 10 links withing tabs linking other tabs

I think i know that i have to change `$tabs.tabs('select', 4);` to `$tabs.tabs('select', id);` but i dont know how to call the "id" in html when i want to create my link.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why make links in the tabs when a person can just click on the tab itself?

Comment: it breaks the text nicely and create more links for the end user to navigate the website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would handle this differently using the href on the link itself, perhaps with a class to indicate that it is an intra-tab link, to determine which tab to load and setting up the handlers in the tabs create event.

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
     create: function(event,ui) {
         $('a.intra-tab',ui.panel).unbind('click').click( function() {
            var id = Number( $(this).attr('href').replace(/#tabs-/,'') ) - 1;
            $('#tabs').tabs('select',id);
            return false;
         });
     }
});

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Alarms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Access Control</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p><span class="bodytext"><a href="#tabs-4" class="intra-tab">Check our services</a></span></p>
    </div>
    ...
```

You could also do it using live handlers.

```
$('#tabs').tabs();
$('a.intra-tab').live( 'click', function() {
    var id = Number( $(this).attr('href').replace(/#tabs-/,'') ) - 1;
    $('#tabs').tabs('select',id);
    return false;     
});
```

Comment: thanks for your help but the code hasnt worked. The strange thing is that is working when you open in a new tab window...

Comment: @fat_mike - I had the wrong event, it should have been the create event, i.e., when the tabs are created.  Note, I probably also should have scoped it to the current tab panel and removed any existing click handlers.  An alternative would be to apply it to all such links using `live`.  Note both methods should apply whether the tabs are loaded dynamically or statically.

Comment: I would have voted for your answer but i cant since my reputation is low at the moment